# add callback function for poll in c

Tags: c, sockets, callback

I am working on a project which requires monitoring on a socket. I know how to do the busy waiting using while-loop to keep reading incoming data if there is one.

Is there a way to setup a callback function so that whenever there is data on the I/O, it will read the data and call my callback function?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  What platform(s) are you targeting?  There are ways to do this on Windows, using Overlapped I/O or I/O Completion Ports.  Maybe there is an equivalent on whatever other platform(s) you want to target.

Comment: There are more-or-less supported socket calls: poll(), select(), epoll() which don't provide a callback, but are better than simple read(). On a fully compliant POSIX system, there is `posix_aio`. For cross platform support, there are several libraries (not part of standard C library) that provide what you want, like `libuv`, `libevent`, etc.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for your reply. The project is on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are more-or-less supported socket calls: `poll()`, `select()`, `epoll()` which don't provide a callback, but are better than simple `read()`. On a fully compliant POSIX system, there is `posix_aio`. For cross platform support, there are several libraries (not part of standard C library) that provide what you want, like `libuv`, `libevent`, etc. –  srdjan.veljkovic